# 3of9 Barcode font on ItextSharp

Tags: c#, itext, barcode

Can I do something like this for my `ITextSharp` font factory

```
Font barCode = FontFactory.GetFont("3of9", 12f);
```

Or how can I easily set a value with the 3 of 9 font?

Comment: You can if you have a font called "3of9" and it is registered.

Comment: @PauloSoares I get a "insertion of Illegal element" error.. any clue what that might be?  Bar code data is 5AB12

Comment: Is this the line throwing the insertion of illegal element error?

Comment: This is the line throwing the error... p.Add(whlsc.CreateImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null));

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a font, I'd use the `Barcode39` class.

It seems that you're still using an old version of iTextSharp. In that old version, a 3 of 9 bar code is created like this:

```
Barcode39 bar39 = new Barcode39();
bar39.Code = "12345ABCDE";
Image img39 =  bar39.CreateImageWithBarcode(content, null, null);
doc.Add(img39);
```

Don't worry about the bar code to be rasterized. The `Image` class can handle vector images too.

Comment: When I do that I get the error: Ambiguous reference between System.WEb. UIControls.Image and Itextsharp.text.image

Comment: When two classes in different packages have different names, you need to use the fully qualified name.

Comment: I have tried this: System.Drawing.Image barCode = whlsc.CreateDrawingImage(System.Drawing.Color.Black, System.Drawing.Color.White);  and I've tried this: iTextSharp.text.Image whlscBC = whlsc.CreateImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null);  ..... both still not working.

Comment: That's strange. I'm not a .NET developer. I know how it works in Java, and I know that many other people have succeeded in making this work in C#, but I can't help any further. You should ask C# developers for advice. In my experience, ambiguous references are easy to solve (both in Java and C#).

Comment: Sounds good I'll mess with it a little more.  I thought I could get the Barcode 39 to work but something still must be missing.

Comment: I used this and it comes back as System.Bitmap.Drawing where the barcode should be.. System.Drawing.Image whlscBarCode = whlsc.CreateDrawingImage(System.Drawing.Color.Black, System.Drawing.Color.White);